# Issue with Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am trying the basic example in dependency injection with property setter. But I'm getting the following compile time error.

```
The method communicate() is undefined for the type Communication
```

I din't find the issue. Can any one please help me that where am I doing wrong.

My Code is as follows,

**POJO Class**

```
package com.websystique.spring.domain.Encryption;
import com.websystique.spring.domain.Massaging;

public class Communication {

    private Massaging messaging;

    public Massaging getMessaging() {
        return messaging;
    }

    public void setMessaging(Massaging messaging) {
        this.messaging = messaging;
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
package com.websystique.spring.domain;

public interface Massaging {
    public void sendMessage();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
package com.websystique.spring.domain.impl;
import com.websystique.spring.domain.Massaging;

public class ActiveMQMessaging implements Massaging{
    public void sendMessage() {
        System.out.println("Sending Message via Active MQ");
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
package com.websystique.spring;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.websystique.spring.domain.Encryption.Communication;

public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-config.xml");
        Communication app = (Communication)context.getBean("communication");
        app.communicate(); // Getting error here
    }
}
```

**Configuration File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="activeMqMessaging" class="com.websystique.spring.domain.impl.ActiveMQMessaging" />

    <bean id="communication" class="com.websystique.spring.domain.Encryption.Communication">
        <property name="messaging">
            <ref bean="activeMqMessaging" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And Finally the project anatomy looks like this,

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that the `Communication` bean has a `communicate()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't define the `communicate()` in your `Communication.java`

The following code will fix your compilation issue.

```
public class Communication {

    private Massaging messaging;

    public Massaging getMessaging() {
        return messaging;
    }

    public void setMessaging(Massaging messaging) {
        this.messaging = messaging;
    }

    public void communicate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```